# How to fix facebook links preview for vue js links?

Tags: vue.js, facebook-debugger

When I try (for testing) to post a link from my vue.js project in my facebook page, the link preview section does not work as expected although I've added the needed `<meta />` facebook tags.

Here is an example of the result:
[image]

How could it be fixed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook's crawler doesn't execute JavaScript. As such, it only sees what you'd see if you hit "view source" on the page - in the case of a Vue app, that's very little.

You'll need to dig into [server-side rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html) of your components.